# I get the Expo Error - TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of undefined in SwipeListView.renderCell

Tags: reactjs, firebase, expo, swipe, react-props

This is the error inside SwipeListView.rendercell

```
  174 | 
  175 | renderCell(VisibleComponent, HiddenComponent, key, item, shouldPreviewRow) {
  176 |     if (!HiddenComponent) {
> 177 |         return React.cloneElement(VisibleComponent, {
      | ^  178 |             ...VisibleComponent.props,
  179 |             ref: row => (this._rows[key] = row),
  180 |             onRowOpen: toValue => this.onRowOpen(key, toValue),
```

This is my code of ./components/SwipeableFlatlist.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {StyleSheet, Text, View} from 'react-native'; 
import {ListItem, Icon} from 'react-native-elements';
import {SwipeListView} from 'react-native-swipe-list-view';
import db from '../config';

export default class SwipeableFlatlist extends Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super (props);
    this.state = {
      allNotifications: this.props.allNotifications,
    };
  }

  markAsRead = notification => {
    db.collection ('all_notifications').doc (notification.doc_id).update ({
      notificationStatus: 'Read',
    });
  };

  onSwipeValueChange = swipeData => {
    var allNotifications = this.state.allNotifications;
    const {key, value} = swipeData;

    if (value < -Dimensions.get ('window').width) {
      const newData = [...allNotifications];
      const previousIndex = allNotifications.findIndex (
        item => item.key === key
      );
      this.markAsRead (allNotifications[previousIndex]);
      newData.splice (previousIndex, 1);
      this.setState ({
        allNotifications: newData,
      });
    }
  };

  renderItem = data => {
    <ListItem
      leftElement={<Icon name="book" type="font-awesome" color="#696969" />}
      title={data.item.book_name}
      titleStyle={{color: 'black', fontWeight: 'bold'}}
      subtitle={data.item.message}
      bottomDivider
    />;
  };

  renderHiddenItem = (data, item) => {
    <View style={styles.rowBack}>
      <View style={[styles.backRightBtn, styles.backRightBtnRight]}>
        <Text style={styles.backTextWhite} />
      </View>
    </View>;
  };

  render () {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <SwipeListView
          data={this.state.allNotifications}
          renderItem={this.renderItem}
          renderHiddenItem={this.renderHiddenItem}
          leftOpenValue={75}
          rightOpenValue={-150}
          previewkey={'0'}
          previewOpenValue={-40}
          previewOpenDelay={3000}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create ({
  container: {backgroundColor: 'white', flex: 1},
  backTextWhite: {color: '#FFF', fontWeight: 'bold', fontSize: 15},
  rowBack: {
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#29b6f6',
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
    paddingLeft: 15,
  },
  backRightBtn: {
    alignItems: 'center',
    bottom: 0,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 0,
    width: 100,
  },
  backRightBtnRight: {backgroundColor: '#29b6f6', right: 0},
});
```

Please tell me what am I missing?

This is where I am making this component inside the "NotificationsScreen.js":-

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {StyleSheet, View, FlatList, Text} from 'react-native';
import {ListItem, Icon} from 'react-native-elements';
import firebase from 'firebase';
import MyHeader from '../components/MyHeader';
import SwipeableFlatlist from '../components/SwipeableFlatlist';

import db from '../config';

export default class NotificationScreen extends Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super (props);

    this.state = {
      userId: firebase.auth ().currentUser.email,
      allNotifications: [],
    };

    this.notificationRef = null;
  }

  getNotifications = () => {
    this.requestRef = db
      .collection ('all_notifications')
      .where ('notificationStatus', '==', 'unread')
      .where ('targetedUserId', '==', this.state.userId)
      .onSnapshot (snapshot => {
        var allNotifications = [];
        snapshot.docs.map (doc => {
          var notification = doc.data ();
          notification['doc_id'] = doc.id;
          allNotifications.push (notification);
        });
        this.setState ({
          allNotifications: allNotifications,
        });
      });
  };

  componentDidMount () {
    this.getNotifications ();
  }

  /* componentWillUnmount(){
    this.notificationRef()
  }*/

  keyExtractor = (item, index) => index.toString ();

  renderItem = ({item, index}) => {
    return (
      <ListItem
        key={index}
        leftElement={<Icon name="book" type="font-awesome" color="#696969" />}
        title={item.book_name}
        titleStyle={{color: 'black', fontWeight: 'bold'}}
        subtitle={item.message}
        bottomDivider
      />
    );
  };

  render () {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={{flex: 0.1}}>
          <MyHeader
            title={'Notifications'}
            navigation={this.props.navigation}
          />
        </View>
        <View style={{flex: 0.9}}>
          {this.state.allNotifications.length === 0
            ? (<View
                style={{
                  flex: 1,
                  justifyContent: 'center',
                  alignItems: 'center',
                }}
              >
                <Text style={{fontSize: 25}}>You have no notifications</Text>
              </View>)
            : (<SwipeableFlatlist
                allNotifications={this.state.allNotifications}
              />)}
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create ({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  },
});
```

What should I do to fix this, any reviews or any type of answers are welcome, Thanks in advance